# PHP JSON Encode conversion into multidimensional array with square brackets for cUrl

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm following [this tutorial](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/onboarding/upfront/#1-make-a-partner-referrals-api-call)

This is supposed to be my output (desired result):

```
{
      "intent": "CAPTURE",
      "purchase_units": [
        {
          "reference_id": "ABC123",
          "amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "100.00"
          }
        }
       ],

      "application_context": {
        "return_url": "https://example.com/return",
        "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancel"
      }
    }
```

However, after a PHP array and converting using json_encode I'm getting this result

```
{
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units": {
        "reference_id": "ABC123",
        "amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": 100
        }
    },
    "application_context": {
        "return_url": "https:\/\/example.com\/return",
        "cancel_url": "https:\/\/example.com\/exit"
    }
}
```

The most noticeable differences can be found here -  the desired result has `"purchase_units": [{` and `}],` while my output is returning `"purchase_units": {` and '},' without the square brackets.

This is my PHP code:

```
$seller = array(
    'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
    'purchase_units' => array(
        'reference_id' => 'ABC123',
        'amount' => array(
            'currency_code' => 'USD',
            'value' => 100.00
        ),
    ),
    'application_context' => array(
        'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
        'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/exit',
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`purchase_units` needs to be an array of arrays. That is, an outer indexed array which becomes a JSON array holding associative arrays that become JSON objects.

```php
$seller = [
    'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
    'purchase_units' => [[ //  note the nested array
        'reference_id' => 'ABC123',
        'amount' => [
            'currency_code' => 'USD',
            'value' => 100.00
        ],
    ]], //  and close it here
    'application_context' => [
        'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
        'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/exit',
    ],
];

$json = json_encode($seller, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

You don't really need the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` but you might want to keep the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option.

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/ZdqcR